# Is a php framework really make a very big(or all) difference in performance e.g Yii vs phalcon

Tags: php, performance, frameworks, yii2, phalcon

OK let me start from the start, I have joined a new team of 5 people for a new and very large project with huge traffic. I have 4 year experience and others are like 10+ experienced. Discussion was on selecting a php framework to build application. There concern and plan was to select a fastest framework. They came up with `Phalcon`( No one ever worked on it before), I added my views on it in discussion that with phalcon we can not dig into code and their community is not very large so if we got stuck somewhere it gonna be difficult for us to meet delivery dates (company is very concerned about delivery dates) But they reject my views by saying no other frameworks are slow, they can't handle large traffic and ultimately response time would be very slow if we go with some other framework. I countered, Project performance not very much depend on framework (yes its do, but just framework can not make a project faster) but more on the right implementation of it like optimised code, good caching mechanism, good server configuration but they rejected my all opinions putting some figure like

```
Phalcon is 50 times faster than Yii (I was recommending Yii), GO language is 70 times faster than PHP etc.
```

My question is from experts here, does frameworks really make this much of difference Because I am not at all satisfied with their points and also with the figures they told me like 50 times faster I don't know from where they got it.
Sorry for bad English, it’s not my native language.

Comment: This is an opinion question and as such not really suited for here. But for my $0.02: The **only** valid argument for everything is "use the correct tool for the job". That is something to be evaluated per project. Using some kind of framework/library compared to vanilla PHP is a given for me personally, because you can focus on your project rather than having to write the support-code. Other than that: See my initial remark.

Comment: I dont want to take the conversation on which framework to use obviously that could be an opnion question. What exactly I am asking is, does project perfromance really that much depend on a framework ?

Comment: That's still partly opinion based. There's no such thing as a generic speed tets, but you have my answer below, as I do agree that speed is the very last thing that should determine what technology to use.

Comment: Phalcon is written in Zephir so you could dig into the source if you had to, or build your own version.

Answer (score 8):

> Phalcon is 50 times faster than Yii (I was recommending Yii), GO language is 70 times faster than PHP etc.

TL;DR: So what if they are? 
We've arrived in a day where adding a newer/faster server costs a fraction of the price of adding a developer.

If I have to chose a tool/technology for a new project I do it because:

**1. I can either work with it/learn quickly how to work with it**

A developer is expensive. The more time they can be productive, the better.

**2. It is well supported and maintained (preferably by an OS community)**

If a bug or a security issue is discovered, it should be fixed quickly. If a new version of PHP comes out, I want the tool to still work (or follow quickly).

Personal note: For that reason I've always been a bit afraid of Phalcon. Even though the PHP API version doesn't change that often, the idea that I need a compatible extension for anything of my site to work is terrifying.

**3. It makes it easier for me to maintain my code.**

As I mentioned: Speed is relative. I will never chose a tool because someone claims it is **X** times faster than **Y**. I need something that allows me to write code that is easily maintained. Developer time is very expensive compared to adding a new instance on `AWS`. So I write my code for clarity and supportability, not speed. Who cares if a template is rendered in 0.001 or in 0.0005 seconds.

**4. It helps me achieve my goals without getting in the way.**

Some frameworks expect you to use their code for everything and don't allow you to do anything on your own (Yes I'm looking at you Symfony!)

In that sense I've loved Yii from the day it was released: It has support and extension for anything but if you want to do things yourself you're allowed to.
It won't get in your way because its simply a set of building blocks that are there if you need it. I think that Yii2 has continued and improved on this. 
But hey, since I've discovered this question via the Yii2 tag, I'm obviously biassed.

In all... Speed does matter, really. No one wants a slow site. 
But it should be the very last deciding point, after every other demand was met.
The total cost should be the deciding factor.

FYI:
You are right about Yii being quick. Safe for Phalcon (but nothing beats a compiled extension in performance) it was the framework with the quickest "boot time" for quite a while back then.

Answer (score -2):

It may help in reducing the lines of code which does not necessarily mean that the project will be finished faster.In my case,i'd prefer to use an MVC since i'm more conversant with some frameworks.